# Indexing PDF documents using Cloudera Search

Tags: indexing, solr, cloudera, morphline

I've been trying to index pdf documents using Cloudera Search aka Apache Solr. First I was able to index twitter tweets. Later I tried to index PDF files. I've created the corresponding collection using `solrctl` with default schema. The morphline file that I used is (I've masked the IP address of zkHost here)...

```
solrLocator : {
  # Name of solr collection
  #collection : collection1
  collection : pdfs

  # ZooKeeper ensemble
  #zkHost : "127.0.0.1:2181/solr"
  zkHost : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181/solr"

  # The maximum number of documents to send to Solr per network batch (throughput knob)
  # batchSize : 100
}
morphlines : [

{

id : morphlinepdfs

importCommands : ["org.kitesdk.**", "org.apache.solr.**"]

commands : [

{ detectMimeType { includeDefaultMimeTypes : true } }

{

solrCell {

solrLocator : ${solrLocator}

captureAttr : true

lowernames : true

capture : [id, title, author, content, content_type, subject, description, keywords, category, resourcename, url, last_modified, links]

parsers : [ { parser : org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser } ]

}

}

{ generateUUID { field : id } }

{ sanitizeUnknownSolrFields { solrLocator : ${solrLocator} } }

{ loadSolr: { solrLocator : ${solrLocator} } }

]

}

]
```

The PDF metadata fields are present in schema.xml file such as...

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

But in the solr /select query output, I'm getting only content and content-type fields. How can I get all the metadata in solr frontend query? Do I need to modify the schema.xml or the corresponding morphline file? Also can I index the fields inside the PDF content?

The command I used to index pdf file is:

```
hadoop --config /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn jar /usr/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-1.0.0-cdh5.8.2-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool -D 'mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx500m' --log4j /usr/share/doc/search-1.0.0+cdh5.8.2+0/examples/solr-nrt/log4j.properties --morphline-file /usr/share/doc/search-1.0.0+cdh5.8.2+0/examples/solr-nrt/test-morphlines/solrPDF.conf --output-dir hdfs://xxxxxx:8020/user/root/outdir --verbose --go-live --zk-host xxxxx:2181/solr --collection pdfs hdfs://xxxxxx:8020/user/root/indir
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. In fact, the PDF file that I was using don't have any metadata. I've tried with other PDF files and got the results. Hope it helps others.